# String reference issue

Tags: c#, string

While creating my game in c# I ran into an issue will making a method which takes in a string, and compares it to another string.

```
if (Player.GetCurrentRoom() == Level.Rooms[2,0]
    && string.Equals(TextMethods.ExtractArgument(input), "fortune"))
{
  Level.Rooms[2, 0].AddExit("north");
}
```

Here it says that input is not recognized, while I have defined it in another class as

```
public static string ExtractInput(string line)
{
  string input = TextMethods.ExtractArgument(line);
  return input;
}
```

edit: here is the extractArgument method:

```
public static string ExtractArgument(string line)
{
  int index = line.IndexOf(' ');
  if (index == -1)
    return "";
  else
    return line.Substring(index + 1, line.Length - index - 1);
}
```

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: I don't understand your code. You're inputting `input` into the `ExtractArgument` method, so I assume `input` is a string. Why have you posted your `ExtractInput` method?

Comment: What do you mean, "input is not recognized"? Do you mean that `Equals()` returns `false`? Why are you showing us the code of `ExtractInput()` that you don't use in the code? What is `input` and what does `TextMethods.ExtractArgument()` do?

Comment: Input is not regonized as a variable in the if-function. Input is a an argument which the player enters to say open a locked door

Comment: You cannot access local variable outside of a function.

Comment: @HerjodeJong - Where do you define `input`?

Answer (score 3):

In your second code you are showing a local variable called `input` inside a method. There is no way this variable is seen outside the method where it's declared.

If you want it to work like you want, you have to declare a property inside the second class:

```
public class Class2
{
    public static string Input { get; set; }

    public static string ExtractInput(string line)
    {
        return TextMethods.ExtractArgument(line);
    }
}
```

then use it in the first code:

```
if (Player.GetCurrentRoom() == Level.Rooms[2,0]
        && string.Equals(TextMethods.ExtractArgument(Class2.Input), "fortune"))
{
    Level.Rooms[2, 0].AddExit("north");
}
```

Comment: That's what the `return` is for.

Comment: @svick: Um what? I believe he is confused about local variables vs class members.

Comment: You said that the value of the `input` local cannot be observed outside of the method. But the same variable is `return`ed, so it can be observed by whatever code calls it. (Not that there is such code in the question.)

Comment: @svick: It cannot be observed in the way he wants i.e. just put the name input in another class.

Comment: And I am confused by your code too. Is there some relation between `Input` and `ExtractInput()`?

Comment: I agree it does seem like he thinks `input` is available outside of the method. Sorry you got downvotes Tudor, your answer is a good attempt considering the info that is available.

Comment: @svick: I can have it assigned inside the method, but that would not be consistent with his original code, where the method has no side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local variable called `input` in one method, you can't directly access it from another method. After the method that contains the local variable finishes, the local variable doesn't exist anymore!

Maybe you're confused by languages like JavaScript, where you can declare a global variable in one method and then use it anywhere else. That's not what happens here.

If you want to work with the result of `ExtractInput()`, you can store it in a local variable in your current method:

```
string line = …;

string input = TextMethods.ExtractInput(line);

if (Player.GetCurrentRoom() == Level.Rooms[2,0]
    && TextMethods.ExtractArgument(input) == "fortune")
{
  Level.Rooms[2, 0].AddExit("north");
}
```

If you want to work with the result of `ExtractInput()` for a longer time (not just in one method), you can store it in a field.